# How to display child elements of <li> at 100% height?

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue trying to make a specific element inside my `<li>` tag to take up 100% of the `<li>` height. Specifically I want an icon I added with a border on its right to fill the entire height of the `<li>` element. [image]

as you can see from the last item in the list, the border for the download icon does not take the entire height of its `<li>` element. How can I fix this?

My code:

```
    <ul>
        <li>طلب المشروع من قبل الجهة المستفيدة<div class="download"><a href="#" class="active"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a></div></li>
        <li class="list_background">وجود قرار تخصيص موقع من قبل المجلس البلدي<div class="download"><a href="#" class="active"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a></div></li>
        <li>بكتاب الامانة العامة لمجلس الوزراء رقم 344 - 3679 المؤرخ<div class="download"><a href="#" class="inactive"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a></div></li>
        <li class="list_background">على مهندس المشروع التأكد من استيفاء ما     يلي حسب ما جاء بكتاب الأمانة العامة لمجلس الوزراء رقم 344-3679 
         المؤرخ (مرفق صورة من الكتاب المذكور) :
         <br>- استلام متطلبات المشروع معتمدة من قبل الجهة المستفيدة.
         <br>- إعداد كراسة طلب المشروع.
         <br>- الحصول على موافقة وزارة  المالية على اعتماد ميزانية المشروع.
         <br>- شهادة خلو الموقع من العوائق.<div class="download"><a href="#"   class="inactive"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a></div></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}
ul li {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 1rem 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: #8c97b2;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: #dadfea;
  line-height: 54px;
  height: 100%;
}
ul li .download {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-right-color: #dadfea;
  display: block;
}
ul li .download i {
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 54px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The CSS you had posted is not CSS it's SASS, please edit the question and add CSS instead to allow us  run it and check the result for you

Comment: Done. Sorry I didn't realize posting SASS would be a problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks for the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve that you have to use table structure which mean make the `li` tag act as table and content act as tabel-cell and icon act as another table cell.

also add a container for the text and never let it flow on any container

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}
ul li {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 1rem 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: #8c97b2;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: #dadfea;
  line-height: 54px;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  width:100%;
}
ul li .download {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-right-color: #dadfea;
  display: tablle-cell;
}
ul li p{
  display:table-cell;
}
ul li .download i {
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 54px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <ul>
        <li><p>طلب المشروع من قبل الجهة المستفيدة</p><div class="download"><a href="#" class="active"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a></div></li>
        <li class="list_background"><p>وجود قرار تخصيص موقع من قبل المجلس البلدي</p><div class="download"><a href="#" class="active"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a></div></li>
        <li><p>بكتاب الامانة العامة لمجلس الوزراء رقم 344 - 3679 المؤرخ</p><div class="download"><a href="#" class="inactive"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a></div></li>
        <li class="list_background">على مهندس المشروع التأكد من استيفاء ما     يلي حسب ما جاء بكتاب الأمانة العامة لمجلس الوزراء رقم 344-3679 
         المؤرخ (مرفق صورة من الكتاب المذكور) :
         <br>- استلام متطلبات المشروع معتمدة من قبل الجهة المستفيدة.
         <br>- إعداد كراسة طلب المشروع.
         <br>- الحصول على موافقة وزارة  المالية على اعتماد ميزانية المشروع.
         <br>- شهادة خلو الموقع من العوائق.</p><div class="download"><a href="#"   class="inactive"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a></div></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks your solution worked perfectly! I am now struggling to center the icons vertically within each cell. If its not too much to ask would you know how I can do that?

Comment: @RashedAl-Julaibi No problems at all, let's check it

Answer (score 1):

You now need to align icon vertically to acheive that we need to add sudo element just after your `.download` div to align the icon vertically

```
ul li .download:after{
 content:"";
 vertical-align:middle;
 display:inline-block;
 height:100%;
}
ul li .download a{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-middle: middle;
}
```

Check the result [HERE](http://codepen.io/w34/pen/QyJrwQ)

and check [this article](http://w34.co/tutorials/5-ways-to-align-elements-vertically/) for a guide to align elements vertically

Hope everything working fine with you

Comment: @RashedAl-Julaibi Good luck ;)